# Catalog View with pagination (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to build a catalog with posts that I get with a query, each page of the catalog will have 27 spots for posts (except for the last page). The problem is that some posts need two spots if there was an image attached when the post was created. I don't have a field in the database that tells me if the post have an image or not, I would add it if is necessary. So far I have this two possible solutions:

1) Get the 27 results and then loop trough them to see how many posts have images and then calculate an offset of the posts that where not displayed so the other page would start with the correct number.

2) Add a field in the database for tracking if a post has an image attached and then run a query with a conditional so I get only the posts I need to get the 27 spots filled.

The problem that I'm having is on how to keep track of these offsets. What happens if the user wants to go to the last page? Do I need to query all the posts and then calculate the offset for that last page?

I'm hoping I'm making some sense, sorry for my english too, I'm not a native english speaker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `remember` , always post what you have tried so far. update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can join both the tables if results are correct and convinent as expected by you and secondly in codeigniter you don't have to worry about the pagination stuff for last and first, the pagination library takes cares for that. For more details on pagination library, visit the below link:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html